# How to concat table names to columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Lets say I'm joining two tables in mysql

```
Owners - id, name
Pets - id, name, owner_id
SELECT pets.*, owners.* FROM pets JOIN owners ON owners.id=pets.owner_id
```

The results come back with multiple id and name columns. Is there a way to get the columns to be returned in a way that distinguishes the tables like `pets.id` and `owners.id` without specifying every column name?

Comment: Possible solution may be [found on the question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911698/rename-a-select-column-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table_name` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(" ", table_name,".", column_name, " as `", table_name, ".", column_name, "`")) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='my_table_name';
```

Result:

```
 my_table_name.id as `my_table_name.id`, my_table_name.name as `my_table_name.name`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name the columns?

```
SELECT pets.id AS pets_id,
   owners.id AS owners_id,
   pets.name AS pets_name,
   owners.name AS owners_name
FROM pets JOIN owners
ON owners.id=pets.owner_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm looking to do this without manually specifying every column